# Calculate sum(position*element) for a vector array in C++

Tags: programming-languages, c++

Consider vector<int> C

I aim to calculate $\displaystyle \sum_i i*C[i]$  using some stl library. In there any stl function there to do that?

Comment: Yes, `std::inner_product` will help you with that. However, this question has nothing to do with computer science (but rather, programming) and is more suitable for [SO].

Comment: Since the solution is a one liner, it doesn’t really belong on stack overflow either. Unless you need a solution that runs in n/2 cycles.